# scipy.optimize.curve_fit optimise warning

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a gaussian plot and a lorentzian plot to a set of resonance data, but scipy.optimize.curve_fit function returns the error 'OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated'. I need the covariance of the parameters to calculated the error in the fits- any ideas how to get rid of it?

My code is:

```
popt1,pcov1 = opt.curve_fit(gaussianfit, E, I, p0=[E0,I0,sigma])
errorp1 = (pcov1)**0.5 
print 'error in gaussian fit =', errorp1 
plt.plot(E, gaussianfit(E,*popt1), '-', label='Gaussian Fit') 

popt2,pcov2 = opt.curve_fit(lorentzfit, E, I, p0=[E0,I0,gamma])
errorp2 = (pcov2)**0.5 
print 'error in combined fit =', errorp2 
plt.plot(E, lorentzfit(E,*popt2),'-', label='Lorentzian Fit') 

#plot gaussian and lorentzian fits combined
errorp = (pcov1 + pcov2)**0.5 
print 'error in lorentzian fit =', errorp #print error
plt.plot(E, (gaussianfit(E,*popt1) + lorentzfit(E,*popt2))/2, '-', `label='Combined fit')
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: How good is the fit? Have you plotted data+fit? Odds are the fit is bad.

Comment: Yeah, the fit is fine against the data, just need the errors

Comment: Only guessing, but I'd try passing a Jacobian to help estimation.

Comment: A what now? I'm a beginner so not entirely sure what you mean, sorry!

Comment: The `jac` keyword of [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html): the gradient of the model function with respect to each parameter.

Comment: Without data it is not easy to help. Could you provide some?

Comment: you should not need to provide an analytic Jacobian for a fit to data with a Gaussian or Lorentzian function.   But, you might want to post a complete example if you actually want help.  Also: you might the lmfit python library helpful -- this has predefined Gaussian and Lorentzian models and will return estimated uncertainties (assuming they can be estimated).

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding a reasonable initial guess for parameters `p0` helped in avoiding the `OptimizeWarning`. Without providing `p0`, the algorithm might throw the warning and return an array with all parameters equal to one.